# Error occured with Blob Cache in

Tags: 2013

I am getting the following error in Event viewer, after enabling Blob Cache :

An error occured in the blob cache.  The exception message was 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'.

Answer (score 3):

Reset the cache by going to Site settings -> Site collection Object cache -> Reset object cache.
Make sure to select "Force all servers to flush their object cache", this will regenerate the cache on the next visit to the page.

Comment: did this.. but didnt work

Comment: It is not even blob cache related anyway.

Comment: Not available in public site for Office 365. I have images that are not visible, looking for a way to clear the cache and see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In siutations like this, I tended to make use of `WinDbg`, the Windows debugger available from Microsoft. `WinDbg` would allow you to attach to the IIS process that is serving the SharePoint site, and then you can catch and analyse exceptions which you may not see in the SharePoint UI.

This could help you figure out, in your case, what file is missing.

Here are some articles that can help you get started:

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaevans/intro-to-windbg-for-net-developers)

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918174044/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/13/windbg-and-psscor2-for-sharepoint-developers.aspx)

http://www.parallelfun.com/2012/11/using-windbg-to-debug-sharepoint.html

I won't lie to you, there is a steep learning curve to using `WinDbg` and the tools to debug what's going on, but it's a very powerful way of working out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have same exact issue. I am getting the error while accessing anonymously to files in draft or pending mode.

I discovered a wierd thing. I am getting this error for web application that configurated with http**s** AAM. It's using for SSL offloading and there is an internal zone configuration with http protocol for same host and same zone.

If I delete "http" AAM url then the error disappears.

I digged w3wp dump but couldn't find anything. Only thing that I found is something goes wrong in "Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl" method. I tried to dissamble this method using Reflector, but I couldn't open.